# Accessing values using JSON Object in Javascript which has special characters

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var obj = JSON.parse("total(PC+CH)":"50", "Name":"Doe"}');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.total(PC+CH);
```

Here is the json which has some special characters like `+` and `()`. But unable to access the element value using `total(PC+CH)` since it has some special characters.

How can we get the value of `total(PC+CH)`?

NOTE: I dont want to use indexing, i want to use `total(PC+CH)` and get the value

Comment: use `obj["total(PC+CH)"]`

Comment: var data = {"total(PC+CH)":"50","Name":"Doe"}
var stringifyData = JSON.stringify({"total(PC+CH)":"50","Name":"Doe"})

var parsedData = JSON.parse(stringifyData)

console.log(parsedData['total(PC+CH)"])